# Elif vs If trouble

Tags: python

Something that's confusing me is If statements vs Elif statements. If they can both be run and both do the same thing, then what's the difference? For example:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number 1-10 "))
if num == 1:
    print("I is the roman numeral for 1 ")
elif num == 2:
    print("II is the roman numeral for 2 ")
elif num == 3:
    print("III is the roman numeral for 3 ")
else:
    print("invalid number please try again")
```

This code can and will run, but what's stopping me from just using an If statement instead of an elif? I read that elifs are faster, but I don't know how true that is if at all.

I've tried going back and removing the if statements and replacing them with elif statements and vice versa, but I just don't see the difference.

Comment: the semantics are totally different, and it is very important to understand. Just a bunch of `if`s will *run only based on the condition*. But if you use `if ... elif...` then the `elif` will **only** run if previous `if` and `elifs` did not succeed!

Comment: They don't do the same thing. Your own example program behaves differently if you replace any `elif` with just `if`.

Comment: @kaya3 ah, correct, the `else` clause!

Comment: Try changing your tests to `num <= 1`, `num <= 2`, etc. Then compare `if` to `elif`. You'll see the difference, even without an `else` case.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics are totally different, and it is very important to understand the difference. Just a bunch of `if`s will *run only based on the condition*. But if you use `if ... elif...` then the `elif` will **only** run if previous `if` and `elifs` did not succeed!

In your case, your conditions are *mutually exclusive* so the behavior is exactly equivalent. But suppose your conditions were *not* mutually exclusive. Consider the different behaviors between:

```
x = 1
if x  == 1:
    print("I am solitary")
elif x < 12:
    print("I am less than a dozen")
```

which simply prints:

```
I am solitary
```

versus:

```
x = 1
if x  == 1:
    print("I am solitary")
if x < 12:
    print("I am less than a dozen")
```

which prints:

```
I am solitary
I am less than a dozen
```

Also note, because of your `else` on the last `if`, the behavior isn't exactly equivalent.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'm going to continue working on if vs elifs with the examples given.